# Have a field/variable display before the super reference inside of a method:JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Looking for input from Java Expert(s):

How does a variable, that is needed to display before the information of the super called inside of a toString() method work?

The variable does display, but it displays at the bottom than at the top of the information. Also, relocating the variable above the super causes a "cannot find symbol"error.

It's understood that in a constructor the super-call must always come first. This seems to be the same way when referenced in methods.

How do I have the variable below display at the top before the information is displayed from the super method in toString()?

```
 public class Apple extends Fruit
    {
    String apples="Snack:"; 
    //Class Constructor
   //Super Constructor
       public String toString()
    {
    String result=super.toString();
    result+=apples+"\n";
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can just do `String result =  apples + "\n"; result += super.toString(); return result;`

Comment: "This seems to be the same way when referenced in methods." - it's not the same way; that restriction is only present in constructors, in methods you're free to call a superclass method whenever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the result to apples worked.

Also otherposter thank you for verification. So the super-method can be called anywhere in any order inside other method except constructor.